# node tools/downloadWebRTC.js command fails when installing "react-native-webrtc" package

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-webrtc

I am trying to install the package "react-native-webrtc" but getting this error (yarn install react-native-webrtc --verbose):

```bash
react-native-webrtc
verbose 189.970120017 Error: /Users/samwin/dev/MobileAgent/node_modules/react-native-webrtc: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node tools/downloadWebRTC.js
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/samwin/dev/MobileAgent/node_modules/react-native-webrtc
Output:
Downloading https://github.com/jitsi/webrtc/releases/download/v100.0.0/WebRTC.xcframework.tgz...
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.199.108.133:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '185.199.108.133',
  port: 443
}
    at ProcessTermError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at ProcessTermError.MessageError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at new ProcessTermError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:790:113)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:25884:17)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
error /Users/samwin/dev/MobileAgent/node_modules/react-native-webrtc: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node tools/downloadWebRTC.js
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/samwin/dev/MobileAgent/node_modules/react-native-webrtc
Output:
Downloading https://github.com/jitsi/webrtc/releases/download/v100.0.0/WebRTC.xcframework.tgz...
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.199.108.133:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
```

The folder react-native-webrtc exists in node_modules, but when I try to build the app in Xcode, then it throws error like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73459843/webrtc-rtcvideorenderer-h-file-not-found).

BTW: I can download the file when opening the url in the browser.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to download the .tgz file manually (which should be done actually in tools/downloadWebRTC.js) and extracted it to corresponding location. Now the Xcode build works fine.